# How to use Content-Type: Multipart/Related

Tags: firefox, cgi, mime

I want to send a binary file to the user and have some HTML display on the browser.  I'm using a CGI-BIN script with apache2.  I found [this example on page 4](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2387.txt).  The link also shows details about the multipart/related content-type.  Here's what I tried so far:

```
Content-Type: Multipart/Related; boundary="boundary-content"; start=""; type=\"text/plain\""

--boundary-content
Content-Disposition: inline
Content Type:text/plain
Content-ID: <abc>

hi

--boundary-content
Content Type:application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=myfile
Content-ID: 2

...

--boundary-content
```

The whole thing after the first `Content-Type` line shows up as a single plaintext attachment.  How can I make the browser say `hi` and prompt to download `myfile` with contents of `...`?

Answer (score 0):

i do not think browsers understand multipart MIME responses