# How to place a multipart/related request using browser fetch api?

Tags: javascript, browser, couchdb

My api server accepts `multipart/related` kinds of POST reqeust.
But I find no resource which explains how to place one such request using browser fetch api.
Almost all links tells how to use `FormData` , but the content type for form data is not `multipart/related`, which I seek.
I need to upload a JSON along accompanied by various attachment files.
How do I make such a fetch request ?

Is there any standard way to do this , like the `FormData` object ?
Or I have to write it manually ?

This is how I expect my output to be

```
PUT /target/SpaghettiWithMeatballs?new_edits=false HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 1030
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="864d690aeb91f25d469dec6851fb57f2"
Host: localhost:5984
User-Agent: CouchDB

--2fa48cba80d0cdba7829931fe8acce9d
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "_attachments": {
        "recipe.txt": {
            "content_type": "text/plain",
            "digest": "md5-R5CrCb6fX10Y46AqtNn0oQ==",
            "follows": true,
            "length": 87,
            "revpos": 7
        }
    },
    "_id": "SpaghettiWithMeatballs",
    "_rev": "7-474f12eb068c717243487a9505f6123b",
    "_revisions": {
        "ids": [
            "474f12eb068c717243487a9505f6123b",
            "5949cfcd437e3ee22d2d98a26d1a83bf",
            "00ecbbc54e2a171156ec345b77dfdf59",
            "fc997b62794a6268f2636a4a176efcd6",
            "3552c87351aadc1e4bea2461a1e8113a",
            "404838bc2862ce76c6ebed046f9eb542",
            "5defd9d813628cea6e98196eb0ee8594"
        ],
        "start": 7
    },
    "description": "An Italian-American delicious dish",
    "ingredients": [
        "spaghetti",
        "tomato sauce",
        "meatballs",
        "love"
    ],
    "name": "Spaghetti with meatballs"
}
--2fa48cba80d0cdba7829931fe8acce9d
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="recipe.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 87

1. Cook spaghetti
2. Cook meetballs
3. Mix them
4. Add tomato sauce
5. ...
6. PROFIT!

--2fa48cba80d0cdba7829931fe8acce9d--
```

Comment: You are ok to use Axios?

Comment: @TarunLalwani no I wanted to make use of Browser fetch Api, I am creating a lightweight lib.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that none of xhr, fetch and event axios (actually it can use different techniques under the hood) supports `multipart/related` out of the box.

I didn't find any direct specification description however, here you can find some related questions ([Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496032/how-to-use-content-type-multipart-related), [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688933/send-a-post-request-in-ajax-with-content-type-of-multipart-related)) and [researches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806228/browser-support-of-multipart-responses).

So it seems that you should compile your request manually. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262266/xmlhttprequest-multipart-related-post-with-xml-and-image-as-payload) you can find some explanation regarding how to do this.